# Running `ocsigen` gives linking error: `dllssl_threads_stubs.so` image not found

Tags: ocaml, ocsigen

I'm currently fighting with a strange linker issue from `ocsigenserver`. It's apparently looking for ocaml-related openssl dynamic libraries. I have both done a `brew install openssl` (at latest version) and also an `opam install openssl`. But I still get the following error:

```
ocsigenserver  -c /usr/local/etc/web/web.conf
Fatal error: cannot load shared library dllssl_threads_stubs
Reason: dlopen(dllssl_threads_stubs.so, 138): image not found
```

I am not sure what's going on here. If I do an `openssl link` I get

```
Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

Which implies to me that I might need to force ocsigen's build to include these flags, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. I feel like this must indicate that `eliom` or `ssl` must be installed incorrectly, and yet I've just `opam reinstall`ed them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the library manually in the file `your_project_name.conf.in` as `<extension path="where_shared_object_located" findlib-package="dllssl_threads_stubs"/>`, to find the path where shared object file is situated on your machine you can do `ldconfig -p | grep dllssl_threads_stubs` hope it will be helpful.